# Can you re-"init" a Facebook pixel with different dataProcessing options?

Tags: javascript, facebook, analytics, pixel

With the advent of the California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA), it's been necessary for some of our clients to implement Limited Data Usage (LDU) policies for Facebook. Our accepted practice has been to explicitly disable LDU `fbq('dataProcessingOptions', [])` until a user opts out (via a consent plugin). Here's the crux of my problem. Once a user opts out, I'd like to re-initialize the Facebook pixel with LDU enabled `fbq('dataProcessingOptions', ['LDU'], 0, 0)` so that future events on the page are processed using the LDU policies. Is it possible to simply call `fbq('init', '{pixel_id}')` a second time and have this "flag" set?

Comment: Any luck yet? I find it completely bizarre Facebook doesn't address this blatantly obvious paradox. In fact I'd say it's irresponsible of them, especially since it's in their own interest to minimize unnecessary blocking of users. How could anybody not immediately have this question!

Comment: This is one of the better attempts I've found that tries to do 'the right thing' https://community.cookiepro.com/s/article/UUID-73489360-184d-4d4f-29a8-7971a95c2592 - however it falls into the chicken and egg paradox of not knowing for new users whether or not they want to be tracked yet.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome [Facebook Pixel extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc?hl=en) will show what is sent for each event.

I was hoping that maybe sending something like `fbq('trackCustom', 'optOut')` might trigger it to re-send updated dataProcessing options, but it doesn't seem to.

Facebook is shooting everyone in the foot by not making this process clearer - it should absolutely be possible to wipe out data collected for the session and that's clearly the best way to do it.

I've spent all weekend trying to do this correctly from both technical and legal stand point and it's just a nightmare. CCPA is supposed to be opt-out!

This **doesn't** work:

```
// CCPA Notice. We allow California users to opt-out from Facebook's data collection by means
// of our 'Do not sell my information' link at the bottom of our website. Please use this link
// to trigger an opt-out via Facebook's API. Questions: privacy at example.com
fbq('dataProcessingOptions', []);
fbq('init', account_id);
fbq('track', 'PageView');


optOut()
{
   fbq('dataProcessingOptions', ['LDO'], 1, 1000);
   fbq('trackCustom', 'registerOptOut');
}
```

I'd recommend putting some text here because people are out to get us by finding vulnerable websites and this makes it look like I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Forgot to add I also tried ‘init’ again and that didn’t seem to work.